# Cancelar procedimento default do JS do bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, bootstrap

Bom dia,

Estou aprendendo a programar web agora( estudei C# ano passado na faculdade e esse ano é web, então queria me adiantar ), vou programar em asp.net, fiz todo meu "formulario" em  bootstrap, visualmente ficou como eu queria, tudo certo, criei o evento de click no botão para programar ele, porem tudo que eu faço ele envia o formulario e apaga os dados, qualquer dos botoes que clicar, mesmo sem eu programar nada pra eles, falando com um colega meu ele disse que isso e por conta do js , que por default envia o formulario, se tiver mais de um botão todos iram enviar, e eu preciso substituir esse default ! so que eu nao entendo muito de js, é isso mesmo que ele falou? e como eu faria?
 [Segue o video que mostra oq acontece.](https://youtu.be/zTwueNqmF0o)

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste seu código. Caso você esteja utilizando o elemento `button` e ele esteja dentro do elemento `form`, adicione o atributo `type="button"`

Comment: Provavelmente vc está usando o mesmo ID em todos os botões!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por padrão, os botões de formulários irão realizar a ação de "submit", ou seja, pegar os dados que estão no formulário e realizar um "post".

Segue um exemplo de como previnir esse comportamento padrão usando  Jquery.

```js
$('#form-post #btn-post').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Previnido comportamento padrão!')

});
```

```html
<form id="form-post" action="/pagina-processa-dados-do-form" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">Mensagem:</label>
        <textarea id="msg"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button id="btn-post" type="submit">Enviar sua mensagem</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/capoia/pen/yvaEJR @Jorge, eu fiz oq vc disse , realmente funcionou, deixou de dar "submit" porem estou programando em asp.net ( c# ) e mesmo eu tirando o default do botão limpar, e programando ele na parte do asp, ( ta na aba de css do codepen pq nao tem suporte) ele nao limpa os campos, porque?

Comment: @WellingtonCapoia, como se trata de ações realizadas na parte do front, limpe os campos usando Javascript mesmo. [Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorge10/gnLy6ckt/) tem um exemplo que eu criei  utilizando Jquery.

Comment: certo mas eu temia que as outras coisas q fizer no back tmb não funcione, por exemplo, quero fazer algumas verificações nesse formulário, quero tmb que quando clica no botão adicionar adicione as informações em certas variáveis , pra depois quando clicar no botão registrar ele mande essas informaçoes pro bd e etc... to aprendendo ainda, mas achei que seria parecido com c# pra desktop

Comment: Bom, se o que você quer fazer é via .NET, pode dar uma olhada [nesse link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/pt-BR/dd03676d-744b-424f-9acc-8d18c848059e/validao-de-campos-formulario-em-c-aspnet?forum=504) no fórum da microsoft, acredito que lá encontrará um rumo para a solução do seu problema. Obs: Se essa resposta te ajudou, marque-a como correta :D . Abraços!